# How can I create an external shared pref/config file for my Android application?

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to store configuration setting on an external file on the sd card. The app must look into this external file and then retrieve some kind of settings. At the moment i am trying to get it to look into a file and get a name. I know you can store things in shared preferences but they are internally accessed.

Anybody know an external way? Thanks

The idea is to have a simple text file or xml file on the sd card. So when a configuration needs changing it is done thru that file?

EDIT

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"/Config.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line="";
        int c;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            line+=(char)c;
            if(String.valueOf(c) == ";" & line =="name;"){
                String name ="";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have attempted to read in a config.txt file and to separate each value with a ;
But i cant seem to understand exactly how i am going to attach what comes after name; to the variable String name.

the config.txt file has the following:

name;fred
somethingelse;test

The program should know when it has got to name and then set the name variable to fred??

Comment: You mean to share prefs across multiple apps

Comment: no not exactly, its the same application. But once it is installed, if i change the 'name' on the external sd card file, i want the name changed inside the application. I dont want to change the code

Comment: In future i may want to add other settings etc. So something similar to how a website has a config/ini file

Comment: Why not just use SharedPreferences and do it across multiple applications? It's possible: http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/

Comment: Because then i would still need to go into an application edit them. The idea is to have a simple text file or xml file on the sd card. So when a configuration needs changing it is done thru there ?

Comment: @Uzi nice question +1 ,Will you please add the detail of your last comment in your edited question? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi 
I had same kind of preferences reading in Blackberry with (Comma separated or) semicolon separated values. When same development came to android the developers (I was not on android at that time.) This is what they have done.

We had created a text file like this

```
"name";"value";"data_type"
```

For example

```
"application_runs";"1";"int"
```

Or

```
"trial_period_key";"01ab23cd";"string"
```

The data type is hardcoded so we can detect the datatypes. For variable names we also had hardcoded list of preferences. And values can be parsed accordingly. They have written public readable shared preference based on that txt files, to use default values, they have copied a "default.txt" in assets folder along with a copy in SD card.

The drawback of this procedure is

1. You have to be careful about file name and the data written in that file (this is the reason why we had put a default values file in assets so the app doesn't crash)
2. The text file on SD Card must be readable, you have to program it along with parsing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: in the android code how do i read the file and know where the data is being separated

Comment: Using FileInputStream you can read the file and you can split the string using '\n' for each set of records and ';' or ',' for each record.

Comment: do you happen to know where i could see an example of this? thanks